# How to put Unity webapp on Google app engine

Tags: java, php, python, google-app-engine, unity-game-engine

I have completed an mini game by unity, named "penguins_test".
I have exported 2 files:

```
penguins_test.html 
penguins_test.unity3d
```

And now, I want to use Google App Engine service to host as a server.
So user can go to website like, "http://penguins_test.appspot.com", to play the game.
However, I am new with the service and the user interface look very complicated.

Can anyone help me to achieve the goal?
Or any online tutorial can teach me to do this?
I prefer to use php or python as the web programming language, or java can be an alternative if it can help to solve the problem.

Please help! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To run your application on App Engine,first you have to download the Google AppEngine SDK to your local machine and before that to need to register your self with App Engine. Go through to the link [1]. You can create your application in Python, Java, Php and GO. But I prefer to go through Python or Java. You can find the tutorials on links [2][3].

You just follow the docs, and I hope you will be able to deploy you application on appspot.com. Also refer to the pricing of the Instances you will run on Google Cloud [4].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs

[2] Python: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstartedpython27/introduction

[3] Java: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/introduction

[4] Google Pricing: https://cloud.google.com/pricing/

Answer (score 0):

There was a very similar question asked on the [unity forums](http://answers.unity3d.com/questions/166099/deploy-unity-web-application-to-google-app-engine.html)  (link attached ) . Hope it answers your question!

Comment: clicking on that links show that it is currently unavailable. You should add details to this answer as a link only answer is not much use when the link does not work :)

Comment: Where did this link to?